# alignment issue with css ul li tags

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using the following code,

> http://jsfiddle.net/wHdYH/

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="hide">Code 1</li>
        <li class="hide">Code 2</li>
        <li class="hide">Code 3</li>
        <li class="hide">Code 4</li>
        <li class="hide">Code 5</li>
        <li class="hide">Code 6</li>
        <li class="hide">Code 7</li>
        <li class="hide">Code 8</li>
    </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".hide").click(function(e) {   
        $(this).toggleClass("hideit");
   });
});

ul li.show {
    list-style: inside;
    padding-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height:16px;
}
ul li.hideit {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    padding-left: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But the issue is when i click it, the text goes to the right and click on again it comes to its same position

I am trying the way is when i click the li the list-style should come to none, but the text should not move

I am checking with IE7+ browsers and all OPera, Safari, FF, Chrome

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the padding from hide-it

```
ul li.hideit {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w8hcP)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `padding` from your class `hideit`:

```
ul li.hideit {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  /*padding-left: 35px; Remove this*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/wHdYH/1/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `padding-left: 35px;` from your rules for `ul li.hideit`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wHdYH/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

When you click, a class is added to the element! `hideit`.

And for that class, you're using

```
padding-left: 35px;
```

And on a re-click, the class is removed and indirectly the padding is removed from the element!

This is causing the issue, remove it! And your issue will be fixed!

Once you remove it, the element won't move any further!

Comment: remove padding with IE 10, the text moved to the extreme left direction now

Comment: No no, try to use `padding-left: 15px;` the default one :)